# posting image on FB from sdcard using AJAX in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have almost tried every possibility and sample of code. getEncodeImage is returning a constant base64string which i have checked on w3schools.com by try yourself returning an image. Base64Binary is another function which i had read on a post where it was mentioned by decoding this way image was posted to facebook wall. if i pass JSON.stringify(decodedPng) I get error URL is not properly formatted and if i ignore JSON.stringify then error is illegal invocation.

```
cmdPost.addEventListener("click", function() {
        outputlog("Post to wall...");



        //added
        var canv = document.querySelector('img#smallImage');

       var imgData = getBase64Image(canv);

        try {

            var testimage = getEncodedImage();

            //var testimage = getEncodedImage();
            var encodedPng = testimage.substring(testimage.indexOf(',') + 1, testimage.length);
            var decodedPng = Base64Binary.decode(encodedPng);

            //var encodedPng = imgData.substring(imgData.indexOf(',') + 1, imgData.length);
            //var decodedPng = Base64Binary.decode(encodedPng);

            //alert('decodedPng=' + decodedPng);

            $.oajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed",
                jso_provider: "facebook",
                //commented and added below by mubashar
                //jso_scopes: ["read_stream", "publish_stream"],
                jso_scopes: ["read_stream", "publish_stream", "publish_actions"],            //, "publish_actions"
                jso_allowia: true,
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    message: "Testing Some Application Ignore My Status for few days!",

                    //source: "http://www.info2gsm.com/VH.png"
                    source: decodedPng
                    //source: JSON.stringify(decodedPng)
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    alert('posted');
                    outputlog("Post response (facebook):");
                    outputlog(data);
                },
                error: function (e) {
                    alert('not posted');
                    outputlog(e);
                }
            });

        } catch (e) {
            alert('error occured = '+ e);
        }



    });
};





function getEncodedImage() {
    return "data:image/jpeg;base64,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"

    //return "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"
}


var Base64Binary = {
    _keyStr: "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=",

    /* will return a  Uint8Array type */
    decodeArrayBuffer: function (input) {
        var bytes = (input.length / 4) * 3;
        var ab = new ArrayBuffer(bytes);
        this.decode(input, ab);

        return ab;
    },

    decode: function (input, arrayBuffer) {
        //get last chars to see if are valid
        var lkey1 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(input.length - 1));
        var lkey2 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(input.length - 2));

        var bytes = (input.length / 4) * 3;
        if (lkey1 == 64) bytes--; //padding chars, so skip
        if (lkey2 == 64) bytes--; //padding chars, so skip

        var uarray;
        var chr1, chr2, chr3;
        var enc1, enc2, enc3, enc4;
        var i = 0;
        var j = 0;

        if (arrayBuffer)
            uarray = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
        else
            uarray = new Uint8Array(bytes);

        input = input.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9\+\/\=]/g, "");

        for (i = 0; i < bytes; i += 3) {
            //get the 3 octects in 4 ascii chars
            enc1 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(j++));
            enc2 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(j++));
            enc3 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(j++));
            enc4 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(j++));

            chr1 = (enc1 << 2) | (enc2 >> 4);
            chr2 = ((enc2 & 15) << 4) | (enc3 >> 2);
            chr3 = ((enc3 & 3) << 6) | enc4;

            uarray[i] = chr1;
            if (enc3 != 64) uarray[i + 1] = chr2;
            if (enc4 != 64) uarray[i + 2] = chr3;
        }

        return uarray;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suffered complete 3 days and finally got solution by merging two solutions. I am using jQuery Mobile for Android development under Telerik appbuilder. Facebook API for JavaScript was very inconsistent so I took this example from [Communication with Facebook Graph using OAuth2](https://github.com/Icenium/sample-facebook-api).

From this example I just bypassed their solution for posting as it was not letting me post images for that I used the following solution. Please note steps for posting images to Facebook using jQuery mobile.

**canvas1 is a html5 element of canvas type.**

1. download the code from https://github.com/Icenium/sample-facebook-api change appid
2. comment the code in cmdPost button
3. Add the following piece of code in your js file

code:

```
if (XMLHttpRequest.prototype.sendAsBinary === undefined) {
    XMLHttpRequest.prototype.sendAsBinary = function (string) {
            var bytes = Array.prototype.map.call(string, function (c) {
                return c.charCodeAt(0) & 0xff;
            });
            this.send(new Uint8Array(bytes).buffer);
        };
    };

    cmdPost.addEventListener("click", function () {

        jso_ensureTokens({
            "facebook": ["read_stream", "publish_stream", "publish_actions"]
        });


        outputlog("Post to wall...");


        try {


            drawCanvas();

            postCanvasToFacebook();

        } catch (e) {
            alert('error occured = '+ e);
        }



    });
};




function postCanvasToFacebook() {

    var data = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    var encodedPng = data.substring(data.indexOf(',') + 1, data.length);
    var decodedPng = Base64Binary.decode(encodedPng);

    var tok = jso_getToken("facebook");
    postImageToFacebook(tok, "info2gsm", "image/png", decodedPng, "www.info2gsm.com");
};



function postImageToFacebook(authToken, filename, mimeType, imageData, message) {

    try {
        // this is the multipart/form-data boundary we'll use
        var boundary = '----ThisIsTheBoundary1234567890';
        // let's encode our image file, which is contained in the var
        var formData = '--' + boundary + '\r\n'
        formData += 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="source"; filename="' + filename + '"\r\n';
        formData += 'Content-Type: ' + mimeType + '\r\n\r\n';
        for (var i = 0; i < imageData.length; ++i) {
            formData += String.fromCharCode(imageData[i] & 0xff);
        }
        formData += '\r\n';
        formData += '--' + boundary + '\r\n';
        formData += 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="message"\r\n\r\n';
        formData += message + '\r\n'
        formData += '--' + boundary + '--\r\n';

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('POST', 'https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos?access_token=' + authToken, true);

        xhr.onload = xhr.onerror = function () {

        };
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);
        xhr.sendAsBinary(formData);
        alert('Posted Successfully.');
    } catch (e) {
        alert('Not Posted Error Occured.'+ e);
    }




};



var canvas;
var context;
var centerX;
var img;
var authToken;
function drawCanvas() {

    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas1");
    context = canvas.getContext("2d");

    img = document.querySelector('img#smallImage');

    context.drawImage(img, 0, 0,430,280);
        context.fillStyle = "rgb(231,222,201)";
        centerX = canvas.width / 2;
        context.textAlign = 'center';
        context.font = 'italic bold 16px sans-serif';
        context.fillText("Model = will appear here", centerX, 70);
        context.fillText("Price = will appear here.", centerX, 130);
        context.fillText("Others = will appear here.", centerX, 190);
};


var Base64Binary = {
    _keyStr: "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=",

    /* will return a  Uint8Array type */
    decodeArrayBuffer: function (input) {
        var bytes = (input.length / 4) * 3;
        var ab = new ArrayBuffer(bytes);
        this.decode(input, ab);

        return ab;
    },

    decode: function (input, arrayBuffer) {
        //get last chars to see if are valid
        var lkey1 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(input.length - 1));
        var lkey2 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(input.length - 2));

        var bytes = (input.length / 4) * 3;
        if (lkey1 == 64) bytes--; //padding chars, so skip
        if (lkey2 == 64) bytes--; //padding chars, so skip

        var uarray;
        var chr1, chr2, chr3;
        var enc1, enc2, enc3, enc4;
        var i = 0;
        var j = 0;

        if (arrayBuffer)
            uarray = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
        else
            uarray = new Uint8Array(bytes);

        input = input.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9\+\/\=]/g, "");

        for (i = 0; i < bytes; i += 3) {
            //get the 3 octects in 4 ascii chars
            enc1 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(j++));
            enc2 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(j++));
            enc3 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(j++));
            enc4 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(j++));

            chr1 = (enc1 << 2) | (enc2 >> 4);
            chr2 = ((enc2 & 15) << 4) | (enc3 >> 2);
            chr3 = ((enc3 & 3) << 6) | enc4;

            uarray[i] = chr1;
            if (enc3 != 64) uarray[i + 1] = chr2;
            if (enc4 != 64) uarray[i + 2] = chr3;
        }

        return uarray;
    }
}
```